# Convert Yaml to excel

Tags: python, excel, yaml

Hey just a heads up I am new to coding as a whole.
My yaml files look like this:

```
**e5testing-dev**             e5-api-599bd6cc7c-66dhc                                        1/1     Running   1          32d
**e5testing-dev**             e5-fe-688b49df9-rlvb9                                          1/1     Running   0          32d
**e5testing-dev**             e5-reports-f74686b5f-27txl                                     1/1     Running   0          32d
```

I need to make a script that takes the first 2 points of data only and makes it into a excel file with col A being the first data point and col B being the second.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Are you sure that's YAML? It doesn't look like YAML.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.